# Running 2 domains on nginx doesn't work

Tags: php, nginx

I've been struggling to find a solution for a few hours. I have one node.js server running that's being redirected by nginx and another server i'm trying to launch via the normal way assigned to 2nd domain. I have two conf files in sites-enabled. 2nd domain redirects to first

File 1 - node.js server port redirected

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://VPS-IP:2368;
    }
}
```

File 2 - php website

```
server {

        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.domain2.pl domain2.pl;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/slucas.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/slucas.error.log;
        root   /var/www2/dokuwiki;
        index doku.php;

        location ~ ^/(data|conf|bin|inc) {
                return 404;
        }

        location ~ ^/lib.*\.(gif|png|ico|jpg)$ {
                expires 31d;
        }

        location /tips {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ http://blog.slucas.fr/en$1 permanent;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki;
        }

        location @dokuwiki {
                rewrite ^/_media/(.*) /lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1 last;
                rewrite ^/_detail/(.*) /lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1 last;
                rewrite ^/_export/([^/]+)/(.*) /doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2 last;
                rewrite ^/tag/(.*) /doku.php?id=tag:$1&do=showtag&tag=tag:$1 last;
                rewrite ^/(.*) /doku.php?id=$1&$args last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock;
        }
}
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's ubuntu 14.04. So I should copy that file into site-available and then create a symlink? I will try this
EDIT: Doesn't change anything

Comment: If you already have it in site-enabled it should work. It's however standard to have them in site-available... then you can remove the symlink (disable the site) without removing the actual config. What happens if you disable the vhost containing the proxy for node? Does the second vhost work?

Comment: Hmm doesn't look like. It must be something wrong with it I guess. It's pretty weird since I used step by step tutorial for this one. I will work on fixing it as this should cause both problems right now. Thanks for reminding about such basic thing

Comment: Try changing the line `listen [::]:80;` to `listen 80;` Using square brackets indicates that it should listen to IPv6 instead of IPv4.

Comment: Doesn't fix anything unfortunately. It acts like it just doesn't see this server, but it is there...

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. =/

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate your help. I must have done some stupid mistake that I'm going to find after few hours of trying. This is actually my first time with nginx and it hasn't been good so far :). Have a good night!

Comment: `nginx` will only read the new configuration if it is restarted. `nginx` reads the `nginx.conf` file which may contain `include` directives to pick up other files (such as files in `site-enabled`). What is the contents of your `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: @RichardSmith http://pastebin.com/JQbwKDpw

Comment: Do you mean if you open `http://domain2.pl`, it shows the content of `http://domain1.com`? Is URL being changed, or it is remaining `http://domain2.pl`?

Comment: Probably there is an error in the config, and Nginx simply doesn't load it. Try `sudo nginx -t` to check for errors, and then `sudo nginx -s reload` if it is OK, to apply changes.